# PHP regular expression - filter number only

Tags: php, regex

I know this might sound as really dummy question, but I'm trying to ensure that the provided string is of a number / decimal format to use it later on with PHP's number_format() function.

How would I do it - say someone is typing 15:00 into the text field - what regular expression and php function should I use to remove the colon from it and make it only return the valid characters.

preg_match() returns array - so I can't pass the result to number_format() unless I implode() it or something like this.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `123.4.5 or 123:4\5 or abs:4:5` -> what digit do you want in result?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Using [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) or [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) is likely the best way to validate a number here, but to answer your question you could try using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead. This example removes all non-numeric characters:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Just put a "." inside the `[brackets]`. E.g. `'/[^.0-9]/'` -- note that if it's outside the brackets it will become a wildcard. And, this will cover 90% of your use case but will also allow any order so edge cases like "123." and ".123" will work. A good idea is to test out your regexes against examples you know should or should not fail. A site like [this one](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) works great.

Comment: Besides the website cited by @buley, another very good one is https://regex101.com!

Comment: i was using  intval on big int, and it was giving me max int value which is 2147483647, so this works good for me.,

Comment: It's nice to know that in the current day and age one can replace `[^0-9]` with `\D`

Answer (score 47):

To remove anything that is not a number:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input);
```

Explanation:

- `[0-9]` matches any number between 0 and 9 inclusively.
- `^` negates a `[]` pattern.
- So, `[^0-9]` matches anything that is not a number, and since we're using `preg_replace`, they will be replaced by nothing `''` (second argument of `preg_replace`).

Answer (score 16):

This is the right answer

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $yourstr);
```

This function return **TRUE(1)** if it matches or **FALSE(0)** if it doesn't

*Quick Explanation :*

**'^' :** means that it should begin with the following ( in our case is a range of digital numbers [0-9] )
*( to avoid cases like ("abdjdf125") )*

**'+' :** means there should be at least one digit

**'$' :** means after our pattern the string should end
*( to avoid cases like ("125abdjdf") )*

Answer (score 7):

You can try that one:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get only the numbers in a regex string is as shown below:

```php
$output = preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $input);
```

Comment: does anyone know where the PHP documentation for the `\D` special character is? I can only find mention of it in this note: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#89364 but would like to find the actual docs for it - thank you

Comment: **Character d Meaning**: Matches a number, equivalent to [0–9].
For example: `/d/` or `/[0–9]/` matches ‘2’ in “B2 is the suite number.”

**Character D Meaning**: Matches any non-numeric, equivalent to [0-9].
For example: `/D/` or `/[0-9]/` matches ‘B’ in “B2 is the suite number.”

**Source**: https://medium.com/@mena.meseha/the-most-commonly-used-php-regular-expression-collection-d60e8b62f21e

Answer (score 3):

use built in php function `is_numeric` to check if the value is numeric.

Comment: I'm using is_numeric - but this only return boolean - so if it's not I'm left with no value. The problem I'm facing here is that during testing of the application someone has typed the colon (:) instead of dot (.) as decimal separator - and this has caused an error with number_format()

Comment: 123.4.5 -> what digit will be?

Comment: `is_numeric` will return `true` for `-234, -10` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you want only whole numbers.

```
function make_whole($v){
    $v = floor($v);
    if(is_numeric($v)){
      echo (int)$v;
      // if you want only positive whole numbers
      //echo (int)$v = abs($v);
    }
}
```