# How do I remove the spaces from my image name?

Tags: php, wordpress, replace, lowercase

In addition to having the image name all lowercase, I'd like to change any spaces to a dash.

```
<img src="/SC/images/<?php echo strtolower(the_title('','',false)); ?>-header.jpg" border="0" />
```

Comment: [What is the difference between get_the_* and the_* template tags in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25612372/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"product_image/" . str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple spaces can be removed using `str_replace()`:

```
$image = "foo and bar.png";

// foo-and-bar.png
echo str_replace( " ", "-", $image );
```

A more complicated search/replace could be done using a regular expression:

```
$image = "foo2   and_ BAR.png";

// foo2-and_-bar.png
echo preg_replace( "/[^a-z0-9\._]+/", "-", strtolower($image) );
```

In this example, we permit letters a-z, numbers 0-9, periods and underlines - all other sequences of characters will be replaced with a single dash. The filename is converted to all lower-case prior to being ran through the replacement function.

Comment: Can we make it work with both the strtolower and the str_replace?

Comment: @user1373974 See my update for an example of using `strtolower` with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the output with a str_replace such as the following.

```
<img src="/SC/images/<?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower(the_title('','',false))); ?>-header.jpg" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower(the_title('','',false)));
```

Answer (score 0):

My [favorite regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474088/php-regular-expression-filter-number-only/5474143#5474143) for sanitization:

```
echo strtolower( preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/', '', preg_replace( '/\s/g', '-', the_title( '', '', false ) ) ) );
```

This removes all non alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Yep - still need to know how to preserve the current strtolower call.

Comment: That should be fine (str to lower before or after shouldn't matter) but this doesn't touch on the fact you need spaces to dash first... Updating.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how such a replace can help.
If you have an actual image with spaces in the name - it wouldn't be shown after replace.
you need to properly encode it with `urlencode()` instead

if you want to replace in the image name, you have to do it on the image, not on the link.
if you need whatever "sanitization" it have to be done on the image, not on the link.
if you want to encode an URI part - use `urlencode()`

every programmer's action have to be sanely chosen, not just randomly picked out of nowhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**strtolower()**" to converts the title to lowercase and "**str_replace( ' ', '-', YOUR_STRING )**" to replace all spaces in the title with dashes.

Try replacing your code with this:

```
<img src="/SC/images/<?php echo str_replace( ' ', '-', strtolower( the_title( '', '', false ) ) ); ?>-header.jpg" border="0" />
```

If you want to write it in a simpler form use this:

```
<?php
$post_title = the_title( '', '', false );
$image_name = strtolower( $post_title );
$image_name = str_replace( ' ', '-', $image_name );
$image_name .= '-header.jpg';
?>
<img src="/SC/images/<?php echo image_name; ?>" border="0" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
$path = strtolower(the_title('','',false)).'.header.jpg';
$filepath =  formatfilename($path);  // remove space and special character from basename of file.

<img src="/SC/images/<?php echo $filepath;?>" border="0" />



function formatfilename($filename) {
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($filename);
        $extension = isset($fileInfo['extension']) ? $fileInfo['extension'] : '';

        // Remove special characters and replace spaces with underscores
        $formattedfilename = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '_', $fileInfo['filename']);

        // Remove leading and trailing underscores
        $formattedfilename = trim($formattedfilename, '_');

        return $formattedfilename . ($extension ? '.' . $extension : '');
 }
```