# Why echoing a local variable inside the same function is not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the flowing Code :(see down)

I defined a local variable named post_author_nickname

Why I can't use it inside the same function as HTML echo?

I'm using the function directly instead of assigning it to variable

---

### The Code

```
function head_scripts() {
    $options = get_option( 'ps_plugindev' );
    if ( isset( $options['twitter'] ) && !is_admin() ) {
            $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
            $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
              $post_author_nickname =  the_author_meta( 'nickname', $post_author_id );
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function setT() {
                    var b = document.createElement('a');
                    b.classList += "twitter-share-button";
                    b.setAttribute("data-text",  "<?php echo $post_author_nickname ?>" );
                };
            </script>
        <?php
}
```

---

```
"< ? php echo $post_author_nickname; ? >"
```

Not working

```
"< ? php echo the_author_meta( 'nickname', $post_author_id ); ? > "
```

Working

### Edit 1 :

Thanks [@mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario) for suggesting reading the question 
[What is the difference between get_the_* and the_* template tags in wordpress? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612372/what-is-the-difference-between-get-the-and-the-template-tags-in-wordpress)
but I didn't understand what the answer? or how it is related

### Edit 2 :

### I checked

- [What is the difference between get_the_* and the_* template tags in WordPress? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612372/what-is-the-difference-between-get-the-and-the-template-tags-in-wordpress)

NOTE: I'm not familiar with php (10%) and only use it for wordpress my background is in c#

### EDIT 3 :

After reading  [@mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario) suggested [anser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612372/what-is-the-difference-between-get-the-and-the-template-tags-in-wordpress)
 multible times I got it.

When [Gaurav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6244815/gaurav) sugesited in his [anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46021710/4879683) changing

```
$post_author_nickname =  the_author_meta( 'nickname', $post_author_id );
```

### To

```
$post_author_nickname =  get_the_author_meta( 'nickname', $post_author_id );
```

I didn't note the deferent between **the** and **get** prefix to the function name'

Now I understand

Usually, I deleted the question if it is marked as duplicate.

I will leave this note if some one like me didn't get it.

thanks [Gaurav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6244815/gaurav) and [@mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function instead of the_author_meta.

```
get_the_author_meta()
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/