# Quick PHP/RegEx function to find letter

Tags: php, regex

I've got a string that can only have letters in it, so all I need is a little function to return true if if only has letters or false if there's a number in it.

I have:

```
function checkstring( $stringvar ){
   if(preg_match("/\d/", $stringvar))
   return false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried?

Comment: use ctype_*() functions

Comment: this topic here in stackoverflow may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474088/php-regular-expression-filter-number-only

Comment: So what happens when you try it?

Comment: Your code indentation style is... well let's be kind and say "interesting". It actually took me a couple of read-throughs to understand what you were even trying to do there, the two `return` statements, one line after another, at the same indentation level is very opaque. Every line of code should speak for itself and it should be clear what is associated with what - which is why I pretty much never omit `{}` braces around control structure code blocks, even if they are only one line. This is my personal opinion, but I know I'm not alone in holding it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
function checkstring($stringvar){
  return ! preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z]/", $stringvar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
function checkstring( $stringvar ) {
    return ( 1 == preg_match( '/^[a-z]*$/i', $stringvar ) );
}
```

the `[a-z]` represents the letters. Here you can add any char you want to allow. If the string contains unallowed chars the function will return false. The modifier `i` at the and makes your chars case insensitive, just remove it if you want to differ between upper and lower case.