# how to differentiate string and integer

Tags: php

Today i came across this problem, how to split out / differentiate is str and is int from a random input? Example, my user can input as below:-

1. A1 > str:A, int:1
2. AB1 > str:AB, int:1
3. ABC > str:ABC, int:1
4. A12 > str:A, int:12
5. A123 > str:A, int:123

my current script is using substr(input,0,1) to get str and substr(input,-1) to get int, but it will give error if having input for case 2,3,4,5 or any others style of user input

Thanks

Comment: Just use some [pregmatch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function to find some number (0-9 ^^)

Comment: This has already been answered by the looks of it: [stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474088/php-regular-expression-filter-number-only

Comment: @jimmy - dunno if you misposted the link, but that's nothing like the same question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list($string, $integer) = sscanf($initialString, '%[A-Z]%d');
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression like the following.

```
// $input contains the input
if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]+)?([0-9]+)?$/", $input, $hits))
{
    // $input had the pattern we were looking for
    // $hits[1] is the letters
    // $hits[2] holds the numbers
}
```

The expression will look for the following

```
^               start of line
([a-zA-Z]+)?    any letter upper or lowercase
([0-9]+)?       any number
$               end of line
```

`(..+)?` in this the `+` means "one or more" while the `?` means `0 or 1 times`. So you are looking for sth that is whatever long and appears or doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a regex to identify and match String and number part: Something like

```
if (!preg_match("/^.*?(\w?).*?([1-9][0-9]*).*$/", $postfield, $parts)) $parts=array();
if (sizeof($parts)==2) {
    //$parts[0] has string
    //$parts[1] has number
}
```

will silently ignore invlid parts. You do still need to validate length and range of the parts.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? regular expressions

```
$str = 'ABC12';
preg_match('/[a-z]+/i', $str, $matches1);
preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $str, $matches2);

print_r($matches1);
print_r($matches2);
```