# Trim comma and whitespacing from number

Tags: php, numeric

I am using this function to convert square meters to square foot.

```
$sinput = rtrim(get_field('fl_area'), ", \t\n");  
if(trim($sinput) == "0"){echo ' ' ;} else {$soutput = metersToSquareFeet($sinput); echo $soutput . ' sq. m (' . number_format($sinput ) . ' sq. f)' ;} 

function metersToSquareFeet($meters, $echo = true)
{
    $m = $meters;
    $valInFeet = $m*10.7639;
    $valFeet = (int)$valInFeet;
    if($echo == true)
    {
        echo $valFeet;
    } else {
        return $valFeet;
    }
}
```

Problem I have is with line:

```
rtrim(get_field('fl_area'), ", \t\n");
```

The user enters the number in the format `3,246` and i want to convert this to `3246` for my function to work.

Of course I could also modify the function somehow and not use `rtrim` in the first place

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options but probably your easiest one is to remove all non-numeric characters.

Not sure what your **get_field** does but assuming it just gets the field from the Input you could use regex like so.

```
$sinput = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $get_field('fl_area') );
```

Also see: [PHP regular expression - filter number only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474088/php-regular-expression-filter-number-only)

Comment: You may use `\D` instead of `[^0-9]`

Answer (score 2):

`rtrim` only removes characters from the end of the string, not the middle. Use `preg_replace`:

```
$sinput = preg_replace('/[,\s]+/g', '', get_field('fl_area'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) to remove all occurrences of commas and spaces from the string:

```
$m = str_replace(array(',',' '), '', $m);
```

Or even [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$m = strtr($m, array(',' => '', ' ' => ''));
```

This is likely to be faster than regular expessions. However, if the number of function calls are minimal, the difference wouldn’t be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str_replace(array(',',' '), '', get_field('fl_area'));
```