# Get parts of strings with PHP

Tags: php, substr

i'm trying to substract parts of a string in a variable with php, refeering in a specific text condition: `class="image-GET_THIS_NUMBER"` and storing it into an array. The variable is something like:

```
$content = '<p>
    <img src="#" alt="" class="image-1">
    <img src="#" alt="" class="image-96">
    <img src="#" alt="" class="image-12231">
    <img src="#" alt="" class="image-444312">
</p>';
```

And i need get this:

```
$images = array(1, 96, 12231, 444312);
```

I don't really know if it's possible to do. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Definitely possible, give me a moment and I'll put together an answer for you.

Comment: what you have tried so for ?

Comment: Please search before ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474088/php-regular-expression-filter-number-only

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Regex.
Here you are

```
$content = '<p>
    <img src="#" alt="" class="image-1">
    <img src="#" alt="" class="image-96">
    <img src="#" alt="" class="image-12231">
    <img src="#" alt="" class="image-444312">
</p>';

preg_match_all("/class=\"image-([0-9]+)\"/is", $content, $matches);
$images = $matches[1];
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To find all matches in your html string, a regex search will be the ticket.

```
preg_match_all('/class="image-(\d+)/', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: Seems I was a bit too slow, lol. But hopefully we've gotten you what you need :)

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad to hear it. In case you're wondering the difference (albeit small) the " in my answer is not escaped because I used single quotes around the regex pattern, and the /is flags I didn't use make the regex search case insensitive and allow periods to match any character including newlines.